# Gitlab omnibus fails to add ssh key

Tags: ssh, permissions, git, gitlab

tldr: there is no `/home/git` directory where `.ssh/authorized_keys` should be.
Is this the expected with Omnibus installs?
System is Debian 8.2

I'm trying to set up ssh keys for my gitlab user. I can add it into the webui, but on the admin>background jobs page, sidekiq indicates a failed job.

I looked around and people mentioned fixing `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file/directory permissions. However when I look in /home, I do not even see a /git folder, I only see my user folder and lost+found (`/home` is on a separate partition).
Have I misunderstood something? Does the omnibus installer place the auth keys somewhere else, and is also having permission issues there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it by following this article
http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/raketasks/maintenance.html#rebuild-authorized_keys-file

I'm not sure if this is a pre-requisite, but I created the directory and file:
`/home/git/.ssh/`
and
`/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Then I used the permissions settings on [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/567340/gitlab-not-working-with-ssh-keys) answer.
`chmod 0711 /home/git` and `chmod 0700 /home/git/.ssh` and finally `chmod 0600 /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Last, I proceeded with the article's instructions.
I also recreated my ssh key on client-machine with the webui instructions and then added that new public key with the webui.

Didn't see any failed jobs in sidekiq. Made a test repo and attempted to clone it over ssh and it worked.

I hope this is useful to someone else.